# Cannot download and update some android sdk components

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I am installing android studio but while downloading SDK component it fails with following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google
.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository:
Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip':
Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
```

Comment: I have the same problem.I've try to install them through a  VPN connection, but nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a too big file (339 MB). If you don't have good speed internet, it will fail on downloading.

Answer (score 2):

For some, running `as Administrator` or `chmod 777` have corrected the issue.

Comment: I admit, was a shot in the dark. 
I had the Windows version of this issue, and had to uninstall Android Studio after turning off certificate validation `bcedit.exe -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS` 

Still, wish you luck in finding the answer!

Comment: `sudo sdkmanager ...` worked for me. What a pain